# Why does this IP not return a host name?

Tags: networking, ping, hostname

I can successfully ping 77.244.226.204 but it will not return a host name. Why not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for reverse DNS lookups to succeed, there needs to be a valid `PTR` record for the IP in question. In this case, there is no `PTR` record.

Comment: Has the city of Bjarred bought this IP and can therefore modify parameters that you would not normally be able to if you have a dynamic IP ?

Comment: Whois information has the city listed as the assignee of this netblock. So yes, typically in this situation, they have full control over the netblock as well as any reverse DNS entries for the zone. Whether or not they "bought" the netblock or were given it to use by their ISP, we can't really know.

Comment: @bobby: If you really want to know then give [Jonas Bjorkander](http://whois.domaintools.com/77.244.226.204) a call.